# C++ Scrubbing Windows New Line Elements in a String on a Unix Compiler

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, string, unix

I'm using a Unix shell compiler and need to import a Windows .dat file for input. Unfortunately this means there exists native '\r\n' components for carriage returns in the input file.

I'm hoping to scrub these out with something along the lines of the following:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("myFile.dat");

    string array[100];
    int i = 0;

    while(getline(dataIn, str))
    {
        str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());
        str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r'), str.end());
        array[0] = str;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

However this is providing the following error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’
```

for the first erase(), followed by

```
error: request for member ‘erase’ in ‘temp.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::c_str [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]()’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’
```

for the second.

I've attempted `str.c_str().erase` but this has resulted in duplicates of the second error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: (And what's wrong with `dos2unix`?)

Comment: Perhaps use `std::remove`, as `::remove` is a function that removes a file, rather than the `std::remove` function from `<algorithm>`..

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an assignment where the professor has insisted on Notepad editing.  :(

Comment: Ahh, my apologies - I'm using the std namespace. Editing now.

Comment: Right, this is one of many cases where `using namespace std;` comes back to bite you in the behind. The `using namespace std;` only really works when there isn't the same function in the `::` namespace.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha - really good to know! I popped the `std::remove`, but unfortunately it still resulted in `error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’`

Comment: Are you including `<algorithm>`?

Comment: Then @MatsPetersson maybe you should write this as an answer so Miller can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in the code:

1. You if you want to use the algorithm function `remove`, you need to add `#include <algorithm>`.
2. To ensure the `::remove` (which is a function that removes the file named by the `char *` argument) isn't picked up, use `std::remove`.